# Construct boost::fusion::map (and more) through custom macro

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-preprocessor

I have a traits class which contains all signals each class has inside a boost::fusion::map.

Example:

```
template <typename T> struct EventTraits;

class SomeClass;

template <> struct EventTraits<SomeClass>
{
    struct Started;
    struct Finished;
    typedef boost::fusion::map<
        boost::fusion::pair<Started, boost::signals2::signal<void()>>,
        boost::fusion::pair<Finished, boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>>
    > Events;
};
```

Since I will need this kind of traits specialization often, I would like to have a macro which saves me some typing, like this imaginary example:

```
CONSTRUCT_EVENTS(
    SomeClass,
    (Started, void())
    (Finished, void(int))
)
```

How could I implement such a `CONSTRUCT_EVENTS` macro?
As a starting point I had a look at `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` and then at Boost Preprocessor, but I have not yet used the latter so I hope someone can guide me.

Comment: If I'm understand your problem correctly, why does this require a macro?  Can't you use templates for this?  The use of macros should be avoided wherever and whenever possible, even if it leads to a bit more code.

Comment: The macro is not required, it would allow me to "compress" the necessary code. Especially the empty structs, which are only used for the named lookup, would only needed to be put there once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that should work:

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

template <typename T> struct EventTraits;

#define DECLARE_EVENT_STRUCT(r, data, elem) struct BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,elem);
#define DECLARE_MAP_ITEM(r, data, i, elem) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i) boost::fusion::pair<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,elem), boost::signals2::signal<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,elem)> >
#define CONSTRUCT_EVENTS_(Name, EventSeq)                          \
    class Name;                                                    \
    template <> struct EventTraits<Name>                           \
    {                                                              \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_EVENT_STRUCT, _, EventSeq)   \
        typedef boost::fusion::map                                 \
        <                                                          \
            BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(DECLARE_MAP_ITEM, _, EventSeq) \
        > Events;                                                  \
    };                                                             \
/***/

//! Stuff to transform (A,B)(C,D) into ((A,B))((C,D)) so BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH can be used. (sequence of tuples)
#define ADD_PAREN_1(A, B) ((A, B)) ADD_PAREN_2 
#define ADD_PAREN_2(A, B) ((A, B)) ADD_PAREN_1 
#define ADD_PAREN_1_END 
#define ADD_PAREN_2_END 
#define CONSTRUCT_EVENT(Name, EventSeq)                            \
CONSTRUCT_EVENTS_(Name, BOOST_PP_CAT(ADD_PAREN_1 EventSeq,_END))   \
/***/

//! Check the output (I use this on visual studio)
#pragma  message(BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE((CONSTRUCT_EVENT(SomeClass, (Started, void())(Finished, void(int))))))

//! Result (with formatting applied)
class SomeClass; 
template <> 
struct EventTraits<SomeClass> 
{
    struct Started; 
    struct Finished; 
    typedef boost::fusion::map 
        <
            boost::fusion::pair<Started, boost::signals2::signal<void()> >
          , boost::fusion::pair<Finished, boost::signals2::signal<void(int)> >
        > Events; 
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```